# declarativeNetRequest path to dynamically added rules in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I specify in the manifest json file the dynamic rules?
Currently I have:

```
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }]   }
```

And in my `background.js` file I have

```
const blockUrls = ['qwe.com', '123.com'];

    blockUrls.forEach((domain, index) => {
      let id = index + 1;
    
      chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        addRules: [
          {
            id: id,
            priority: 1,
            action: { type: 'block' },
            condition: { urlFilter: domain, resourceTypes: ['main_frame'] },
          },
        ],
        removeRuleIds: [id],
      });
    });
```

What should I write in the `path` field?

Comment: Dynamic rules aren't related to static rules so just remove `declarative_net_request` from manifest.json.

Comment: Also, don't call updateDynamicRules for each URL, but instead generate an array of all rules and register them once in one call of updateDynamicRules.